# Using a DLL proxy fails due to an unknown error

Tags: c++, dll

I'm using a dll proxy with the code described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically), but having tons of trouble.

First, I use VS2012 on Windows 7 and the target is on Windows XP. So I needed to:

1. Install VCRedist on the target computer (I'd like to get around that if possible, suggestions will be greately appriciated)
2. Update my VS to at least Update 1 (I've updated to Update 4) to have
   XP compilation support.

I did both of these, and the errors have changed. But still I get this error when the program starts:

```
The application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b)
```

And it doesn't run.

The DLL proxy I'm using is basically the default example from the code project article. I've added a message box and a log file write on the DllMain and it doesn't show, meaning the dll isn't even loaded - But I don't get why.

How can I debug this? Is this a compilation configuration issue?

EDIT:
I've written a testing program that calls LoadLibrary with my dll proxy, and it works okay. So I'm thinking it's not a CRT dlls thing.
Anyway, here's the info from WinDbg after I compiled with /MT (I'm sorry but I had to remove companies and application names):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\AppName\AppName.exe"
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 12400000 12bdb000   AppName.exe
ModLoad: 7c900000 7c9b2000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 7c800000 7c8f6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 60000000 6006d000   C:\WINDOWS\cdmapi32.dll
ModLoad: 73dd0000 73ece000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MFC42.DLL
ModLoad: 77c10000 77c68000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 77f10000 77f59000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 7e410000 7e4a1000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77dd0000 77e6b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77e70000 77f02000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 77fe0000 77ff1000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
ModLoad: 5d090000 5d12a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 774e0000 7761e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 77120000 771ab000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 76080000 760e5000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCP60.dll
ModLoad: 77c00000 77c08000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 76b40000 76b6d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
ModLoad: 76390000 763ad000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
ModLoad: 76380000 76385000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSIMG32.dll
ModLoad: 763b0000 763f9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
ModLoad: 7c9c0000 7d1d7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 77f60000 77fd6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 73000000 73026000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
ModLoad: 00340000 00356000   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll
(dc8.68c): Unknown exception - code c000007b (first chance)
(dc8.68c): Unknown exception - code c000007b (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=0012fc54 ebx=00000000 ecx=0012fc80 edx=7c90e514 esi=7ffdc000 edi=c000007b
eip=7c9673be esp=0012fc54 ebp=0012fca4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!RtlRaiseStatus+0x26:
7c9673be c9              leave
```

I've checked procmon, here's the last few lines:

```
9:56:07.8699734 PM  AppName.exe 496 QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS CreationTime: 8/31/2014 2:14:39 PM, LastAccessTime: 8/31/2014 9:55:22 PM, LastWriteTime: 8/31/2014 7:14:29 PM, ChangeTime: 8/31/2014 7:14:29 PM, AllocationSize: 73,728, EndOfFile: 70,656, FileAttributes: A
9:56:07.8704646 PM  AppName.exe 496 QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS CreationTime: 8/31/2014 2:14:39 PM, LastAccessTime: 8/31/2014 9:55:22 PM, LastWriteTime: 8/31/2014 7:14:29 PM, ChangeTime: 8/31/2014 7:14:29 PM, AllocationSize: 73,728, EndOfFile: 70,656, FileAttributes: A
9:56:07.8709551 PM  AppName.exe 496 CreateFile  C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS Desired Access: Execute/Traverse, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
9:56:07.8713057 PM  AppName.exe 496 CreateFileMapping   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: PAGE_EXECUTE
9:56:07.8714685 PM  AppName.exe 496 CreateFileMapping   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
9:56:07.8718270 PM  AppName.exe 496 CloseFile   C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS 
9:56:07.8724308 PM  AppName.exe 496 Load Image  C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll    SUCCESS Image Base: 0x340000, Image Size: 0x16000
9:56:07.8737372 PM  AppName.exe 496 CreateFile  C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll.2.Manifest NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read/Execute, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
9:56:07.8746961 PM  AppName.exe 496 CreateFile  C:\Program Files\AppName\DllName.dll.2.Config   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read/Execute, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
9:56:09.0143355 PM  AppName.exe 496 Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 4064, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.0468750
9:56:09.0151822 PM  AppName.exe 496 Process Exit        SUCCESS Exit Status: -1073741701, User Time: 0.0156250 seconds, Kernel Time: 0.0468750 seconds, Private Bytes: 2,572,288, Peak Private Bytes: 2,588,672, Working Set: 1,761,280, Peak Working Set: 1,765,376
9:56:09.0158711 PM  AppName.exe 496 CloseFile   C:\Program Files\AppName    SUCCESS
```

It seems that it fails searching for the manifest and config files. Is this a problem?

Comment: I don't really get how your question is related to reverse-engineering... You may have a better answer on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: It's a dll proxy - as commonly used in reversing

Comment: considering ntstatus, something's wrong with (your) image. Maybe x86/x64 issue? Who can guess without further info. Open `procmon` and check when the loading breaks, or start debugger if you really want to debug.

Comment: I've checked procmon and added the info to the question

Answer (score 4):

The problem happens due to the fact that the required CRT DLL's are missing on the target machine. To avoid this you can link against the CRT statically. 
Use the **Multi-threaded (/MT)** linker flags in VS. This way you also do not need to install *VCRedist* on target computer.

More info *[here](http://www.davidlenihan.com/2008/01/choosing_the_correct_cc_runtim.html)*

Another way is to install *[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)* on the target machine, open the required PE file and note which dependencies are missing and then copy the required dependencies there.